# How to write file on AWS EC2 storage optimized drive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, drive

I'm interested in trying out an EC2 storage-optimized `i3.large` instance for some benchmarks, but I can't figure out how to use the 475GB drive it comes with. How can I write a file to it and read it back?

Some things I've tried:

- `df -h` does not show it as a volume
- looked through AWS documentation. Lots of info about how to get metadata about the drive with `lspci` and `nvme` commands, but nothing about where the drive is mounted / how to read or write data from it

Comment: [Make instance store volumes available on your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html#making-instance-stores-available-on-your-instances)